# Set tooltip text for each element in an SWT Combo widget

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I've been looking around for ages and can't seem to find whether this is possible or not.

I have a Combo widget populated with some strings and wan't to set the tool tip text to be something different for each item in the Combo widget. i.e. When you mouse over an item in the Combo widget a string is displayed above the mouse icon.

For example if there are 2 items in the Combo widget, Foo and Bar, can you set the tool tip text to be "Foo" when you mouse over Foo and "Bar" when you mouse over Bar??

Any advice/insights would be great, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480261/java-swing-mouseover-text-on-jcombobox-items

Comment: I have already come across that answer but I am using SWT, not java swing. So I can't use this example

Comment: Use a selection listener that changes the `Combo`'s tool tip text on selection change?

Answer (score 2):

The solution by Edward Thomson is probably the best one, but if you don't want to code, you might use TooltipCCombo class from [blog post Tooltip enabled CCombo for SWT](http://s-weber.blogspot.cz/2010/08/tooltip-enabled-ccombo-for-swt.html) (at your's own risk).

Comment: Cheers for the answers guys, I'l try them out when I get back to that bit of the project. Moved on for now.