# Set tooltip for filterable and editable jComboBox items

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, netbeans-8, jtooltip

I have a JComboBox that is filterable and editable.
I would like to set a tooltip for each item in the JComboBox - I figured I should use JToolTip for this.

I tried to use the answer from this link: [Java Swing: Mouseover text on JComboBox items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480261/java-swing-mouseover-text-on-jcombobox-items).

But when the JComboBox shows filtered items, the order of the JToolTip index is changed. In this case I don't know how to set the right JToolTip text for each JComboBox item.

I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some advice concerning to this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question, putting a description of the situation on top, and adding some whitespace - I hope this will make it easier to understand.
You could further improve your question by adding a sample of your code - a [Minimal, Complete, Verifable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is best. Good luck, and hope you'll get help soon!

Comment: @S.L. Barth: Thank you very much for modification of my question. I understand that there is an art to asking good questions.

Answer (score 1):

> jComboBox is filterable and editable.

How do you provide a tooltip if the combo box is editable and the user adds a new item to the combo box?

> But when jComboBox shows filtered items, the order of jToolTip index is changed.

Don't base your lookup on index. Instead you need to base the lookup on the item (or toString() value of the item). For this you can use a `HashMap`

```
HashMap<String, String> tooltips = new HashMap<String, String>();
tooltips.put("A", "tooltip for item A");
tooltips.put("B", "tooltip for item B");
```

Then in the renderer you can use:

```
String tooltip = tooltips.get( value.toString() );
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. About provide a tooltip if the combo box is editable: I tried many ways to implement but without success. Now I am working by following your answer, results will report later.