# Can't add a new item with tooltip to JComboBox (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox that contains **items that all have a tooltip**. To add the tooltips I used the stackoverflow solution here [Java Swing: Mouseover text on JComboBox items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480261/java-swing-mouseover-text-on-jcombobox-items#4480209). Now I want to take this one step further and **add new items to the combobox** and add a new tooltip for each new item.

To test this I created a simple test project with a combobox and a button. When you click the button, a new item is created and added to the combobox. My problem is that I can't figure out how I can add the proper tooltip at the same time. In this case it seems that I'm not allowed to manually add the tooltip String to the list.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ComboBoxWithToolTips extends JPanel
{
    JComboBox<String> combo;
    ComboboxToolTipRenderer renderer;

    JButton button;

    String[] items;
    List<String> tooltips;

    public ComboBoxWithToolTips()
    {
        items = new String[] {"red", "blue", "black"};
        tooltips = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"});
        combo = new JComboBox<>(items);
        renderer = new ComboboxToolTipRenderer();
        renderer.setTooltips(tooltips);
        combo.setRenderer(renderer);
        add(combo);

        button = new JButton("Add");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                String name = "new" + random.nextInt(100);
                String tooltip = name + " tooltip";

                combo.addItem(name); // Add the new item
                renderer.tooltips.add(tooltip); // Add the new tooltip to the list
            }
        });
        add(button);
    }

    public class ComboboxToolTipRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
    {
        List<String> tooltips;

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
        {

            JComponent comp = (JComponent) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                    list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

            if (-1 < index && null != value && null != tooltips)
            {
                list.setToolTipText(tooltips.get(index));
            }
            return comp;
        }

        public void setTooltips(List<String> tooltips)
        {
            this.tooltips = tooltips;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tooltip Test");

        ComboBoxWithToolTips comboBoxWithToolTips = new ComboBoxWithToolTips();
        comboBoxWithToolTips.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.getContentPane()
            .add(comboBoxWithToolTips);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

The frame opens and every combobox item has its tooltip. But when I press the "Add" Button I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException   at
>   java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)    at
>   ComboBoxWithToolTips$1.actionPerformed(ComboBoxWithToolTips.java:48)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

The solution from the prior mentioned stackoverflow topic **works only for initialization** but **not for dynamically adding new items**.

Does anybody see the mistake or is there a special type of JComboBox for what I m trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
tooltips = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"});
```

`Arrays.asList` returns an immutable list, and you can't add elements to it.

You can create a mutable list like this:

```
tooltips = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}));
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake .. this was driving me insane. Thank you Sir, everything wroks now as it should!